# Autodesk Forge v7: Event Listeners in ES6 Classes

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge, viewer

I followed this [tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/skeleton), and I checked the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/#toolbar-created-event) and onToolCreated should have something to do with TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT. But the other events don't work for me, like onExplodeChanged(). I even checked on the console and it says that `Autodesk.Viewing.EXPLODE_CHANGE_EVENT = "explodeChanged"` and `Autodesk.Viewing.TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT = "toolbarCreated"`. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no equality between `onExplodeChanged` and `Autodesk.Viewing.EXPLODE_CHANGE_EVENT`. You need to register your event handler of `Autodesk.Viewing.EXPLODE_CHANGE_EVENT` in your extension or somewhere in your app yourself.

The [Extension#onToolbarCreated](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Extension/#ontoolbarcreated-toolbar) is a special cause. It's introduced since Forge Viewer v7. See [Migration Guide v6 to v7](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/)

Comment: I was first introduced to onToolbarCreated and then I assumed all the event handlers could be easily listened to the same way

Comment: Ah sorry, no all events have a similar shortcut to `onToolbarCreated` according to our engineering team. :(

Comment: Sorry for the typo. "no all events" -> NOT all events. So, it means only `onToolbarCreated` is supported now